# What can I do with my C# code for me to apply this to my UI in Unity?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, unity-game-engine, account

I'm trying to set up my Account registration system to input data from unity to my database, and so far i have been able to do so through the Inspector, now I want to be able to do this with my UI that i made in Unity, what do I need to do? (P.S. this is my first time posting and i am also a beginner so excuse me if i may not follow some rules and what not)

here is the code i used to input data to my PhpMyAdmin database through the inspector in Unity:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DataInserter : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject inputUserName;
    public GameObject inputEmail;

    string CreateUserURL = "http://localhost/balikaral/insertAccount.php";

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) CreateUser(inputUserName, inputEmail);
    }

    public void CreateUser(string username, string email)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("usernamePost", username);
        form.AddField("emailPost", email);

        WWW www = new WWW(CreateUserURL, form);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to get the input from your input fields [`InputField.text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-text.html)

I recommend to directly use `InputField` fields so you don't need the `GetComponent` calls.

```
public class DataInserter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField inputUserName;
    public InputField inputEmail;

    string CreateUserURL = "http://localhost/balikaral/insertAccount.php";

    public void CreateUser()
    {
        var userName = inputUserName.text;
        var email = inputEmail.text;

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("usernamePost", username);
        form.AddField("emailPost", email);

        WWW www = new WWW(CreateUserURL, form);
    }
}
```

And reference the `CreateUser` method in the Button's `onClick` event.

---

Note however that `WWW` is obsolete and you should rather use [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html)

```
public void CreateUser()
{
    var userName = inputUserName.text;
    var email = inputEmail.text;
    StartCoroutine(CreateUserRequest(userName, email));
}

private IEnumerator CreateUserRequest(string userName, string email)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("usernamePost", username);
    form.AddField("emailPost", email);

    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(CreateUserURL, form))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how would i go about in using UnityWebRequest.Post ?

Comment: There already is an example for `UnityWebRequest.Post` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't do it via PhpMyAdmin, it's a mysql tool for manage mysql thing, I assume you want to create a player's account for your game .
there are two ways to do what you want
1. create a webApi site that accept Http post (recommand), the webapi will have connect to your mysql database , and do the CRUD(Create,Read,Update,Delete) thing
2. create a mysql connection directly to your mysql database, and insert your data to your mysql table. (it's unsafe)

Neigher way, you need to know about the `SQL` language.

Comment: I am using PhpMyAdmin temporarily just to test if the functions are working, i'm planning on using Azure for my actual database, i was thinking if there are things i need to alter to my code in order to insert and get data from my actual database